# Storing a reference vs storing a copy-able object implemented with PImpl?

Tags: c++, qt, software-design

I have a class called `SharedData`, and a `Container` object with ~100k `Individual` objects. Each of the `Individual` objects needs access to the data stored in `SharedData`; because there are so many of them, it's not feasible to store a copy in each. Presently, I store a reference to the `SharedData` object. However, this seems to be considered a code smell; also, it prevents default-constructing the `Individual` objects (for storage in `std::vector`, or `QVector`). As a possible solution to this problem, I've considered restructuring the `SharedData` class to follow the pimpl design pattern:

```
class SharedData {
    QSharedPointer<PrivateSharedData> sharedDataPtr;
public:
    SharedData(...) : sharedDataPtr(new PrivateSharedData(...)) {}
    SharedData(const SharedData &other)
    {
        sharedDataPtr = other.sharedDataPtr;
    }

    ...

}
```

This would allow each `Individual` object to store a copy of the `SharedData` object, would only require `sizeof(QSharedPointer) == 16` bytes of memory per `Individual`, and would allow `Individual`s to be default-constructed and have their `SharedData` member initialized later (e.g. through an assignment operator).

Is this an appropriate change to make? Are their drawbacks that I'm not considering? Is there a more elegant solution, or would this be considered best practice?

Comment: Not clear why you need all the complication or how that helps. You could just store a pointer.

Comment: I'd just keep the references or a pointer. If you apply too many patterns and style guides you could end up with a non-turing-complete language ;)

Comment: For privately owned objects you don't need a shared pointer, a `std::unique_ptr` will suffice (I believe Qt's equivalent is QScopedPointer).

Comment: @alain good to have some peace of mind that other people (who know what they're doing more than I do) think that what I've done so far is okay. Thanks!

Comment: @RustyX `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied; the purpose of holding the private implementation in a `QSharedPointer` was to allow it to be copied.

Comment: For the record, this has nothing to do with PIMPL.

Comment: @NikosC. No? In that case I'm a little confused. My concept of pimpl is that the `SharedData` has a single variable - a pointer to type `PrivateSharedData`- which holds all the implementation, and `SharedData` is basically just a wrapper around that. Is that incorrect?

Comment: PIMPL is not about making data private. It's about hiding an implementation behind an opaque pointer (pointer to object of forward-declared class.) It's used to keep ABI compatibility when changing the implementation. What you have here is a shared pointer to some normal object. In PIMPL, the pointer is not shared. It's owned solely by the class its in. The object behind that pointer contains the implementation of the class. The implementation cannot be shared.

Answer (score 0):

Each `Individual`  Object access to the SAME `sharedData` (i.e there is a unique instance of `sharedData` for n instances of `Individual` ?)

In this case you need a member QSharedPointer in Individual and that will make the job.

From the description of your problem I don't see any need for pimpl idiom.